# Contact Form 7 - acceptance error message position

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

Is there a way to specify the location of the error message for `Acceptance`?
[image: error message]

Here is my code in the form:

```
<p>[acceptance agree box]I have read and accept the <a href="http://somesite.com/?page_id=2300">privacy policy</a>.
```

What I want to do is to place the error message at the purple box(as the image indicated.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and I found that this code worked for me. You will have to find the class of the form-control wrap element that is wrapping your input. Mine was named 'accept-terms'. Yours might be named something different.

CSS:

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.accept-terms input {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.accept-terms span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  clear:both;
}
```

Form Setup:

```
[acceptance accept-terms] Your checkbox or acceptance box 

<br />

[submit class:cta-button "Send"]
```

Here is what it looked like [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZoDf.png)

Here is what it looks like [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Au54.png)